# Postgres Phrase search with tsvector

Tags: postgresql, search

The following code works for phrase searching:

```
SELECT *
FROM companies
WHERE name_tokens @@ to_tsquery(replace('Apple Corporation', ' ', ':* |'))
```

Is there a way to see if over 50% of the words match or a better way to do it?

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM companies a
WHERE name_tokens @@ to_tsquery(replace('TIAA Access Small-Cap Blend Index Fund T1', ' ', ':* &'))
```

is not returning a company with the name 'TIAA-CREF Small-Cap Blend Index Fund Adv' but changing & to | would produce too many unrelated results.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Add an example data and the expected output.

Comment: @klin - Thanks! Let me know if that helps!

Comment: The issue is using Or results in ~210,000 results due to certain words, but using AND doesn't work as the result I'm looking for might not include one word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [pg_trgm extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) may be more suitable to your needs than full text search, e.g.:

```
create extension if not exists pg_trgm;

with companies(name) as (
values 
    ('Small Companies Cooperation'),
    ('TIAA Access Small-Cap Blend Index Fund T1'),
    ('Access Business Corporation'),
    ('Index One Fundation')
)

select name, similarity(name, 'Access Small-Cap Blend Index Fund')
from companies
order by 2 desc

                   name                    | similarity 
-------------------------------------------+------------
 TIAA Access Small-Cap Blend Index Fund T1 |      0.825
 Index One Fundation                       |   0.232558
 Access Business Corporation               |       0.18
 Small Companies Cooperation               |   0.134615
(4 rows)
```

or

```
select name
from companies
where name % 'Access Small-Cap Blend Index Fund'

                   name                    
-------------------------------------------
 TIAA Access Small-Cap Blend Index Fund T1
(1 row)
```